# Issue with a JavaScript I wrote

Tags: javascript, dom-events

I have this code:

```
function getArea (){
    var area1 = document.getElementById('first');
    var area2 = document.getElementById('adart');
        if (area1.style.display.match("none") && area2.style.display.match("none"))
        {
                area1.style.display = 'block';
        }
        else
        {
            area1.style.display = 'none';
        }

}


function getArea1 (){
    var addArticle = document.getElementById('adart');
    var area1 = document.getElementById('first');
        if (addArticle.style.display.match("none") && area1.style.display.match("none"))
        {
            addArticle.style.display = 'block';
        }
        else
        {
            addArticle.style.display = 'none';
        }

}
```

Now, in my html page:

I have two text areas and two buttons.
Each button "activates" a different text area.
All that my code does is to make the property 'display' in each text area to be "block" or "none", also, to make sure that if one text is already visible, the others will not.

The problem is that the first button "edit article" is not working until I click on the second button "add article". The second button works properly.

Any thoughts?

Comment: check if wether you provide default value as block to first button.

Comment: provide `none` to `area1` in default and set condition in `else if` is like `area1.style.display.match("none") && area2.style.display.match("block")`

Comment: and what will be through that condition?

Comment: you said that i need to set a condition.. what code do I need to put in the condition? what that condition checks?

Comment: you need to try the code given in 2nd comment